# Where can I find data for abandoned blocks (74,638 to 74,690) for the Value Overflow Incident when ₿184 billion BTC were accidentally created?

Tags: raw-data, history, chain-reorganization

I already have data for all the Mainchain Blocks. Where can I find data for the orphaned/abandoned blocks (74,638 to 74,690) before the re-organisation occurred?

I can only seem to find information for [block 74,638](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=822.msg10332#msg10332) and the timestamp for block 74,639. I cannot seem to find anymore. I have been digging through waybackmachine without much luck.

Any help appreciated!